Mask last 4 digits but not hyphen using regex
I need to mask the last 4 digits but not hyphen (-) in a credit card number.
For example



If I have a string like:
desired Output




1234-5678-9123-4567-891
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891


1234-5678-9123-4567
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4567


123456789123
xxxxxxxx9123



In any case the last 4 digits should be visible. If in a odd string (just like the first example), the last 4 digits including hyphen(if any) should be visible.
Thanks, I tried below but not working in all cases...
 public static string MaskCreditCardNo(this string value)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
         return value;

     return Regex.Replace(value, "(\\d[\\s|-]?){10,}\\d", match=>
         {
             string CCnumber = match.Value;
             string digits = string.Concat(CCnumber
          .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));
             return (digits.Length >= 12 && digits.Length <= 19) ?
             Regex.Replace(CCnumber.Substring(0, CCnumber.Length - 4), @"\d", "x") + CCnumber.Substring(CCnumber.Length - 4) : match.Value;
     });
 }


You can use a negative lookahead pattern after a matching digit to ensure that it is not followed by 3 or less digits until the end of the string:
Regex.Replace(value, @"\d(?!(?:\D*\d){0,3}\D*$)", "x")

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PONAvJ

Thanks for your solution. It does work for the examples I posted and for various other scenarios too. However, there is one more scenario which I forgot to mention and it is a string like this which has a credit card number as well as an account number and they both should get masked. If there are any other digits say, amount or something it should not masked---

like "Im paying 2700 dollars with my credit card(123456789012345) to my account(12345678)". Here the output should be "Im paying 2700 dollars with my credit card(xxxxxxxxxxx2345) to my account(xxxx5678)". I will mark your post as answered but great if you can suggest on this.

This does works but breaks the earlier scenario of "1234-5678-9123-4567-891", the output should be "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891". I have posted another question having all the scenarios. Glad if you can have a look at that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78481830/regex-for-masking-credit-card-and-account-no
