Regex for masking credit card and account no
I need to mask the credit card (if digits >=12 and <=19) and account number (if digits == 8 or 9). Following should be input/output for various strings--
123456789123 -> xxxxxxxx9123
1234-5678-9123-4567 -> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4567
1234-5678-9123-4567-891 --> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891
123123123123131For8640 --> xxxxxxxxxxx3131For8640
123123123123131to123123123123177 --> xxxxxxxxxxx3131toxxxxxxxxxxx3177
12345678 --> xxxx5678
I m paying 2700 dollars with my credit card(123456789012345) to my account(12345678) --> I m paying 2700 dollars with my credit card(xxxxxxxxxxx2345) to my account(xxxx5678).
Note that in any case last 4 digits should only be visible(including hyphen).
The below code works in all cases except when the the credit card number has the odd total number of digits. For e.g 13,15 or 19. This case does not work with below code -- >
Expected : 1234-5678-9123-4567-891 --> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891
Actual : 1234-5678-9123-4567-891 --> xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-891
private static string MaskIfAccountNumber(this string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        return text;

    return Regex.Replace(text, "[0-9][0-9 ]{6,}[0-9]", match =>
    {
        string digits = string.Concat(match.Value
          .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));

        return digits.Length == 8 || digits.Length == 9
          ? new string('x', digits.Length - 4) + digits.Substring(digits.Length - 4)
          : match.Value;
    });
}
public static string MaskIfContainCreditCardPanorAcctNum(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    var maskedAccountNumber = value.MaskIfAccountNumber();

    return MaskCreditCardNo(maskedAccountNumber);
}

public static string MaskCreditCardNo(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        return value;

    return Regex.Replace(value, "(\\d[\\s|-]?){10,}\\d", match =>
        {
            string CCnumber = match.Value;
            string digits = string.Concat(CCnumber
         .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));
            return (digits.Length >= 12 && digits.Length <= 19) ?
            Regex.Replace(CCnumber.Substring(0, CCnumber.Length - 4), @"\d", "x") + CCnumber.Substring(CCnumber.Length - 4) : match.Value;
        });
}


"does not work" is not a sufficient problem description. What happens in contrast to what you want to happen?

Any credit card no. totaling to odd digits (13,17,19) for e.g 1234-5678-9123-4567-891 gets converted to xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-891. This is incorrect. In any case, the last 4 digits along with hyphen (-) should be visible. So correct output should be xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891. Any change in pattern might impact other mentioned scenarios in question.

I think you could spare yourself from Regex-Headaches by implementing a maintainable solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jnGyfa

@Fildor: I like this much more. And as usual: A developer has a problem. She tries to solve it with a RegEx. Now the developer has two problems.

You can use a positive lookbehind pattern to assert that a matching digit is within 12 to 19 consecutive digits preceded with an optional dash, and use a negative lookahead pattern to assert that the matching digit is not followed by 3 or less digits:
(?<=(?<![\d-])(?=(?:-?\d){12,19}(?![\d-]))[\d-]*)\d(?!(?:-?\d){0,3}(?![\d-]))

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/e0o6Zf/1

Hi @blhsing, I also need to match * with 12-19 digits. So a string "521893******8699" should look like "xxxxxxxxxxxx8699". How can I achieve this with your answered regex above?

Replacing all \d with [\d*] will do: https://regex101.com/r/e0o6Zf/2

Thanks. It works. One last thing if you don't mind. How can I include spaces too? So for a string like "1234 5678 9123 4567", it should be xxxx xxxx xxxx 4567.

You can replace all - with [ -], but the credit card number should then not be mixed with other spaces or it becomes ambiguous whether a space belongs to the credit card number or the rest of a sentence: https://regex101.com/r/e0o6Zf/3

Thanks. I tried using \s and it's also seems to be fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz#

Hi. I think what you mentioned about space changes in your last comment has come across now. I am not getting correct output for "Test 123456789123 Test". It should be coming as "Test xxxxxxxx9123 Test". If I make any change in the regex then it breaks other existing scenarios - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz#. Can something be done to handle this? I can raise a new question if you want. Thanks

Sorry. Please ignore this. It's working.

Hello. I am getting an issue with a string like "Schedule Pmt - Transfer to  183000004". Here 183000004 is basically an account number which can be 8 or 9 digits. But as there is a "space" before the account number it is not masking it to "Schedule Pmt - Transfer to  xxxxx0004". Please refer to https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz#. Thanks

If an account number is not supposed to include a space, don't include it in the pattern: https://regex101.com/r/mX0emt/1

Hi @blhsing. I am having an issue when there is a space before/after in CreditCardNo. For e.g  "from INV 2420852290 to SAV 0165487". Here 2420852290 is 10-digits still it is getting masked. For a CreditCardNo, the range is 12-19 digits. The reason is the space(before or after the digits) which is taken that extra 11th or 12 character i think. The regex in use is "(?<=(?<![\d-])(?=(?:-?[\d\s]){12,19}(?![\d-\s]))[\d-\s]*)\d*". https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz#. Please help if possible. Also, space will be required in case of CCNo such as 1234 5678 9123 4567

I have created a new question too for this scenarios -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78777023/issue-while-masking-credit-card-no-before-and-or-after-spaces
