Issue while masking Credit Card No. before and/or after spaces
I am having an issue when there is a space before/after in CreditCardNo.
For example from INV 2420852290 to SAV 0165487. Here 2420852290 is 10-digits and still it is getting masked.
For a CreditCardNo, the range is 12-19 digits. The reason is the space (before and after the digits) which is taken that extra 11th and12 character i think.
The regex in use is
(?<=(?<![\d-*])(?=(?:-?[\d*\s]){12,19}(?![\d-*\s]))[\d-*\s]*)[\d*](?!(?:-?[\d*\s]){0,3}(?![\d-*\s]))
I tried below code with above regex. Expected is that all the scenarios along with the one which is asked in question should work as it is. The last 4 digits should always be masked with x.
They can be tested using the URL - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz. Thanks
        public static string MaskNewCCNo(this string value)
        {
           var a = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<=(?<![\d-*])(?=(?:-?[\d*\s]){12,19}(?![\d-*\s]))[\d-*\s]*)[\d*](?!(?:-?[\d*\s]){0,3}(?![\d-*\s]))", "x");

            return a;
        }


right now you are masking EVERYTHING BUT the last 3 digits, while you state you would like to mask only the last 4. could you please provide a couple more input values and your desired results for each of them?

this regex would for example mask the last four digits of any number ob 12-19 digits.

Yeah {0,3} does looks like it is masking last 3 but in fact if you see the output in https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz, it is actually masking last 4 digits. The ultimate goal is to mask the last 4 digits and pass all other scenarios mentioned in this link. Thanks

One more solution I came across was to use this code --

private static string MaskCreditCardNumber(this string text)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
return text;
 return Regex.Replace(text, "[0-9][0-9 ]{12,}[0-9]", match => {
     string digits = string.Concat(match.Value
       .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));

     return digits.Length >= 12 || digits.Length <= 19
       ? new string('X', digits.Length - 4) + digits.Substring(digits.Length - 4)
       : match.Value;
 });

}

All the scenarios mentioned in the link would work with this but for string such as "1234-5678-9123-4567-891", the masked output should show "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx7-891" but it is showing as "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-891". If we can solve this, I think all scenarios will be handled.

please include the test cases to your question, so anyone reading your question knows what exactly you want help with

As I mentioned, there are lot of test cases which needs to be taken care of while fixing this issue. These test cases are part of https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gopzoz. Here in this particular question my case is "from INV 2420852290 to SAV 0165487" should not get masked as 2420852290 is not in range of 12-19 digits but as there are spaces around it, the regex is masking it,

Or this demo...

Also see this \G based idea (updated your demo). The other demo (without \G) is here. Both regexes are not efficient, not sure which is worse. :D

Awesome, thanks @bobblebubble. I understand you mentioning that which might be worse (with \G or without \G) :). But from performance point of view, would you advise to go with \G or without it? Both solutions work for me though.

@user3665818 I would go with the \G based pattern. It's probably about 10x-20x more efficient than the other. The other regex does the whole lookaround-check-construct at each digit whereas the \G does the lookbehind stuff just once (from where it chains matches) and only the less costly lookahead-check at each match. Even the other solution I provided is about 5x-10x faster than your current regex I think... probably Wiktor's solution would perform better. To find out, do a benchmark.

The reason your current regex did not work for the sample lies in (?<![\d-*]) which purpose is meant to separate the whole number from text but it just checks for one of the listed characters. Together with [\d*\s]){12,19} that could match the specified amount of digits or whitespace.
Besides I would not use something like [\d-*\s]. In this case (.NET regex) there is no error but it still looks ugly. An unescaped hyphen inside a character class is used to denote a character range. To match a literal hyphen put it at start/end of the character-class or escape it with a backslash.
As per your follow-up question better don't use one (huge) regex for this. It's certainly smarter to go with Wiktor's idea which can be more easily adapted to changing and growing requirements.

Credit Card Number (matching the full number)
The problem lies in distinguishing between the cc- and account-number and separate those from the other text. To be as specific as possible with matching the cc-number - instead of looking for 12-19 digits with spaces or hyphens anywhere in between - better identify the cc-number by starting with 3-4 groups, each containing 4 adjacent digits - optionally followed by 1-3 digits. If the groups are separated by dash or space, capture it and match as far as separator is consistent.
Have a look if the following pattern fits your needs (regex demo).
(?<!\d-?)\d{4}([ -]?)\d{4}(?:\1\d{4}){1,2}(?:\1\d{1,3})?(?!-?\d)


Account Number (from your new question)
You can use the same regex for the account number by just replacing the cc-part with \d{8,9}. Assuming there are no separators in the account-no like in your provided samples (regex demo).
(?<!\d-?)\d{8,9}(?!-?\d)


Combining both patterns
If necessary for your application, you can also combine both patterns into one by alternating between the options inside a non-capturing group - more left option is tried first (regex demo).
(?<!\d-?)(?:\d{4}([ -]?)\d{4}(?:\1\d{4}){1,2}(?:\1\d{1,3})?|\d{8,9})(?!-?\d)


On each resulting match (the full numbers) replace such as \d(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4}) with x to mask all but the last 4 digits with use of the technique that @WiktorStribiżew provides in his answer.
See your updated demo (the combined pattern is in MaskIfContainCreditCardPanorAcctNumNew).

This does work in all scenarios except "Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 351461637 221414441406". Here "351461637" is account number and "221414441406" is CCno. Now it works fine for CCno but for account number, it masks everything. It should mask the last 4 digits only. So it should look like "Biller code 3038 - Receipt No xxxxx1637 xxxxxxxx1406".  This is regex I am using (?<!\d)\d(?:[\s-]?\d){7,8}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4}). Account Number should be 8 or 9 digits only.

Please ignore the regex in above comment as that was meant for Wiktor reply. I tried using this regex as well - Regex.Replace(value, @"(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\d[ -]?)(?=(?:[ -]?\d){8,9}(?![ -]?\d)))\d(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4})([ -]?)", "x$1");

I know this is a different scenario which was not in the question but as all the solutions are there on this page, I am not raising a new question,

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ffgakc

I have posted a different question to handle scenarios related to my last comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781466/issue-in-masking-accountnumber-and-creditcardno-in-a-free-text-field. Please have a look and suggest.

@user3665818 I did another update to my answer (completely changed... as the requirements did). I hope with all provided answers, you can get it solved somehow.

Thanks @bobble bubble. Thanks a lot for all your help and all the scenarios in my demo are working fine with your answer. I know I have been coming up with new requirements but this should be the last one now.  I need to replace asterik (*) too along with the digits in CCNo if it's between 12-19.

So for a string like  "420657******4405" it should get mask to "xxxxxxxxxxxx4405". I am using this Regex right now - Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d-?)\d{4}([ -]?)\d{4}(?:\1\d{4}){1,2}(?:\1\d{1,3})?(?!-?\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4})", "x")); This behavior should work for this regex too Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d-?)(?:\d{4}([ -]?)\d{4}(?:\1\d{4}){1,2}(?:\1\d{1,3})?|\d{8,9})(?!-?\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4})", "x"));

Updated demo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/iYPCeo

@user3665818 for this change all relevant \d to [\d*] → updated demo (cc-number and both numbers). If you also expect such as *****9123-4567 try https://dotnetfiddle.net/7VN03P. I'm out from this topic, glad it helped!

Thanks @bobble bubble and Wiktor for all your help. The scenarios have passed the testing and looking good.

You can add using System.Linq; declaration and use
Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d)\d(?:[ -]?\d){11,18}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4})", "x"))

See the regex demo.
Details:

Get the matches of 12-19 numbers separated with optional - or space, see this regex demo.

Mask the digits inside the match. More details:



\d - a digit that is...
(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4}) - immediately followed with four occurrences of an optional -  or whitespace and a digit.

NOTE: You may use a similar logic for the account number processing.

See your updated code demo here.

This does work in all scenarios except "Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 351461637 221414441406". Here "351461637" is account number and "221414441406" is CCno. Now it works fine for CCno but for account number, it masks everything. It should mask the last 4 digits only. So it should look like "Biller code 3038 - Receipt No xxxxx1637 xxxxxxxx1406".  This is regex I am using (?<!\d)\d(?:[\s-]?\d){7,8}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4}). Account Number should be 8 or 9 digits only.

I know this is a different scenario which was not in the question but as all the solutions are there on this page, I am not raising a new question,

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ffgakc

I have posted a different question to handle scenarios related to my last comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781466/issue-in-masking-accountnumber-and-creditcardno-in-a-free-text-field. Please have a look and suggest.

I wanted to mark this answer correct as well but it is allowing me to mark only 1 answer correct,

Your account number processing can be done in a similar way, without the use of complex regexps that you yourself cannot handle. You did not provide any requirements for the account number regex, I would have included it in my answer. IF the account number is a chunk of 8-9 digits separated with hyphens/whitespaces, you can use the solution you show in your comment, you just used TestCC instead of TestCCAndAccNo.

I need to use TestCCAndAccNo method because there is a free text field wherein user can type any text along with account number and CCNo. Then both of these numbers should get masked. I am calling both MaskCCNo and MaskAccNo from the method MaskIfContainCreditCardPanorAcctNumNew. All the scenarios except "TestCCAndAccNo("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 3514611 221414441406","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 3514 611 xxxxxxxx1406")" are passing. Here as 3514611 is less than 8 digits the MaskCCNo is masking it which is not correct. It should remain as is. Refer https://dotnetfiddle.net/l2PDIw

@user3665818 There is no match, see the regex demo. The problem is that the previous regex, (?<!\d)\d(?:[\s-]?\d){11,18}(?!\d), matches 3514611. So, the resolution depends on what requirements you want to follow. Maybe we can assume that numbers of 5 to 8 digits cannot be matched by CCNo regex? Try Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d)(?!\d{5,8}(?!\d))\d(?:[\s-]?\d){11,18}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4})", "x"))

You need to account for the trailing and leading spaces in your regex. You are currently not.
Here is an example to do that.
void Main()
{
    string input = "From INV 2420852290 to SAV 0165487";
    string pattern = @"(?<=\b(?<![\d-*])(?=\d{12,19}\b)[\d*\s]*)[\d*](?!(?:-?[\d*\s]){0,4}(?![\d-*\s]))";

    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "X");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

This returns : From INV 2420852290 to SAV 0165487
If I increase the number by two like this:
void Main()
{
    string input = "From INV 242085229012 to SAV 0165487";
    string pattern = @"(?<=\b(?<![\d-*])(?=\d{12,19}\b)[\d*\s]*)[\d*](?!(?:-?[\d*\s]){0,4}(?![\d-*\s]))";

    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "X");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

I now get this : From INV XXXXXXXX9012 to SAV 0165487
Here is my reasoning:
Explanation:

\b (word boundary) is used to ensure we start and end at word
boundaries to handle spaces around the digits properly.
(?<![\d-*]) ensures we are not preceded by a digit, dash, or asterisk.
(?=\d{12,19}\b) looks ahead to ensure we have between 12 to 19 digits
followed by a word boundary.
[\d*\s]* matches digits, asterisks, or
spaces.
[\d*](?!(?:-?[\d*\s]){0,4}(?![\d-*\s])) matches a digit or an
asterisk and ensures it's not followed by unwanted characters within
a specific range.

If you just always want to mask then you can do something simple like this:
string pattern = @"\d(?=(?:-?\d){4})";
