Issue in masking AccountNumber and CreditCardNo in a free text field
I am having issue in masking the below strings. For Account Number, the last 4 digits should be shown if it's in the range of 8 to 9 and for Credit Card Number the last 4 digits should be shown if it's in range of 12-19. Below is the format of (input,output):
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 3514616375 221414441406","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 3514616375 xxxxxxxx1406"); //CCNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 351461637 221414441406","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No xxxxx1637 xxxxxxxx1406"); //Both AccNo and CCNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 35146 221414441406","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 35146 xxxxxxxx1406"); //CCNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 221414441406 3514616375","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No xxxxxxxx1406 3514616375"); CCNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 221414441406 351461637","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No xxxxxxxx1406 xxxxx1637"); //Both AccNo and CCNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 22141444140 351461637","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 22141444140 xxxxx1637"); //AccNo should get masked
("Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 22141444140 3514616375","Biller code 3038 - Receipt No 22141444140 3514616375"); //Both should not get masked

I tried the below regex and they work for all scenarios in the demo. But for these scenarios in question, it is not working. It is expected that all the scenarios in the demo as well as this one in question should all work together.
public static string MaskIfContainCreditCardPanorAcctNumNew(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return value;

    var maskedAccountNumber = value.MaskAccNo();

    return maskedAccountNumber.MaskCCNo();
}
public static string MaskCCNo(this string value)
{
      var a = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\d[ -]?)(?=(?:[ -]?\d){12,19}(?![ -]?\d)))\d(?=(?:[ -]?\d){4})([ -]?)", "x$1");

//Tried this too
//var a = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d)\d(?:[\s-]?\d){11,18}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4})", "x"));
      return a;
}

public static string MaskAccNo(this string value)
{
         var a = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\d[-]?)(?=(?:[-]?\d){8,9}(?![-]?\d)))\d(?=(?:[-]?\d){4})([-]?)", "x$1");

//Tried this too
// var a = Regex.Replace(value, @"(?<!\d)\d(?:[\s-]?\d){7,8}(?!\d)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d(?=(?:[\s-]?\d){4})", "x"));
    return a;
}


Is this a different question to yesterday's?

Yes these are different scenarios altogether hence raised a new question

"the last 4 digits should get masked" But all your examples show the last 4 digits are get shown, did I misunderstand?

Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected now. Last 4 digits should be shown and everything else should be masked

So here the requirement is to mask all but the last 4 in a contiguous (not separated by space or dash) sequence of 8-9 or 12-19 digits. This would be less challenging, the \G variant could be like this one: (?:\G(?!^)|\b(?<!-)(?=(?:\d{8,9}|\d{12,19})\b(?!-)))\d(?=\d{4}) or like this less intuitive but more efficient variant (both do not allow word characters to either side).

Thanks a lot for these. Can you please elaborate what exactly it means --- "(both do not allow word characters to either side)"?

@user3665818 If you want to match e.g. no1234567890123abc use something without word boundary (?:\G(?!^)|(?<![\d-])(?=(?:\d{8,9}|\d{12,19})(?![\d-])))\d(?=\d{4}) try to understand the functioning of the patterns we all provided, so you can adapt modificiations yourself (in regex101 explanation of the pattern is on the right side). I guess, new cases  will appear that aren't covered yet.

Thanks @bobblebubble. You are correct, it's important to understand the pattern. With this solution (?:\G(?!^)|(?<![\d-])(?=(?:\d{8,9}|\d{12,19})(?![\d-])))\d(?=\d{4}), all works fine but CCNo with spaces and hypen(-) doesn't work. For example - "1234-5678-9123-4567" and "1234 5678 9123 4567". I am in mid of a release and need to fix it urgently. As you said, I would like to spend more time understanding the patterns but after this release. If you can suggest on this plz. Thanks

Hi @bobblebubble, this should be the last scenario I need to handle. Please suggest what can be done here

Updated demo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/vrv2Sz

@user3665818 As requirements grew I would suggest to use Wiktor's idea (feel good when switching). It's better to adapt and efficient. I edited my answer according to your new requirements - it is now also using this technique.
